# Power to Electrical Panel in Shed

Tags: wiring, generator

We bought a storage shed that is wired with outlets and an internal light/switch running to the breaker box. Attached is picture of the breaker box in the shed. This panel will only be powered by portable generator, no other electrical power source. The generator is 3500W inverter generator with floating neutral ground (not bonded to frame). I plan on installing an L14-30, 30 amp watertight inlet box on the outside, and wiring with 10/3 to the breaker box. The red and black of the 10/3 will go to the top input poles of the panel, and then the neutral and ground wire to the neutral bus bar. Does this setup look/sound correct? Thanks for your help!   [image: shed breaker box picture]

Comment: Distinct lack of clamps on the cables. Does your generator actually have a 14-30 output?

Comment: All the ones of that size-class I see in a quick look are 120V only, not 120/240 (so TT-30 or L5-30 for "the big plug" not 14-30.

Comment: Is the generator 240V?  If it's not you'll need to jumper the panel for 120V *oh wait, you already have*.

Comment: Yes, it's 120V output generator, and yes, I did mention the wrong inlet connector. The generator has an L5-30 outlet connector.

Comment: So, you only need 10/2 with ground from your inlet to the box. Or hot neutral ground 10 AWG THHN in conduit.

Comment: The generator is 120V output. So, all wiring should be clamped where it comes into the box, and I need to make a correction for the bare jumper wire. Using 10/3 input wire, is it correct to attach ground and neutral to the neutral bar?

Comment: Given what the panel looks like, the other end of the wiring probably could stand a skeptical look/inspection before you apply power to any of it.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The ground wire runs the length of the pipe to outside. Was planning on driving 8 foot ground rod to attach to.

Comment: So, I can flip the center breaker, add a filler plate to the right side of that breaker, use 10/2 wire and connect hot to the left input lug (via #6 pigtail), correct? That will power all breakers? Also, add a jumper from neutral bar to the box case if the bar is not grounded to case, right?

Comment: Yes, checking the other end of the wiring would be smart, as you stated. I'll check all of the outlets and the light fixture.

Comment: Yes, all cables need to enter with cable clamps and all conduits need to enter with connectors. So there's some work to do there.  Also you need 2 ground rods unless one passes an impedance test (that costs more than a 2nd ground rod lol).

Comment: So, two ground rods for a 12 x 14 storage building? I assume they should be tied together with ground wire, and spaced a certain distance apart?

Comment: If you pull all the breakers, you'll be able to see where the busses connect. You want all three connected to the same buss. That evidently will mean other side, opposite one of the other breakers (so up or down one space from where it is.) Other panels use different layouts, so you always want to look, not assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cables entering the box need to be clamped. You probably need a filler plug for the big hole the cable on the left is coming in through, and to re-route it through a smaller knockout that a clamp will fit in (you might also be able to fuss with reducer rings, but it's a fuss.)

You have clarified in comments that your generator is actually 120V-only with an L5-30 connector. Since the generator ground is floating, the generator ground and neutral both connect to the neutral bar. There should also be an explicit bond between the neutral and the metal case, which is typically a green screw, but I don't see that here - I'd put in a jumper to a #10-32 threaded hole in the box if that's missing. Your input connector would also be an L5-30, presumably.

The wire tying the two input lugs is probably too small for them, and they are most likely not listed for 2 wires in the lug. Simple solution for 120V-only if you only need 3 or 4 circuits is to flip the center breaker to the other side, positioned so all 3 breakers are on one bus, buy a filler plate for the hole it leaves, and only connect to one lug, as you are in fact only bringing in 120V from your generator.

As far as I can figure, lacking a look at the label (which should tell you exactly, as well as the correct torque value for tightening the various screws,) similar panels in the HOM series require a minimum of #6 wire on the main lugs, so you'll likely have to splice your #10 hot wire to a #6 (or two #6 if wanting both busses hot) to correctly connect to the main lug. Your #10 neutral and ground can likely go in smaller holes in the neutral bar, rather than even use the large lug connection there.

The white pipe pretending to be conduit should be replaced with conduit or removed, and the replacement conduit would need a proper box connection fitting.

There appears to already be a big ground wire going somewhere - you need one going to a couple of driven ground rods or some other suitable ground electrode, such as a concrete foundation ground if there happens to be one here.

Comment: That wire should probably not be bare. Even though it is connecting two lugs that are accessible when the cover is off (so therefore bare wire should be pretty much the same), it is a little bit of a hazard and bare always means ground. Could flip breakers around as you described. Could also bring in power on 10 AWG cable and just add two pigtails to the hot wire to split it to the two lugs.

Comment: That wire is very likely several violations in one. Correcting it (correctly) will likely cost more than not needing it (by flipping the middle breaker so all are on one bus) unless the OP has the unlikely unicorn that is a 240V 3500 Watt generator in the USA/Canada market.